# Query post and sort by custom value calculated with custom field on cpt

Tags: wp-query, query-posts

I shall made a query post ad I have some issue to sort the posts.

I have multiple custom fields that calculated in php (with some operators) a final value for each posts - I call it $price.
These prices will be calculated also considering some input values from a form.

It is a numeric value (for example price) and I'd like to sort the query post by all of these price.

Usually I use

```
    'meta_key'  => 'price',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_type' => 'NUMERIC',
    'order' => 'DESC',
```

But in this case I do not have custom fields 'price', because it is a value that I calcuted on php starting from other custom fields.

Is there a way to proceeed?

EDIT: I'm trying to find a solution and a similar approach has been made here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36369702/wordpress-sort-the-posts-returned-by-wp-query

So I tried to array my values and use usort to sort correctly them.

---

$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
while ($my_query->have_posts()): $my_query->the_post();

```
    $value_1 = get_post_meta($post->ID,'value_1',true);
    $value_2 = get_post_meta($post->ID,'value_2',true);
```

//    $value_3 = input by user - coming from form

```
    $price = $value_1*$value_2*$value_3;
    $price_array[]= array( 'ID' => $post->ID,
                            'price' => $price);

endwhile;

usort($price, function ($item1, $item2) {
    if ($item1['price'] == $item2['price']) return 0;
    return $item1['price'] < $item2['price'] ? -1 : 1;
});


$sorted_posts = array();

foreach($price_array as $key)
{
    $sorted_posts[]=$key['ID'];
}


$args = array(
    'post_type'               =>    'my_cpt',
    'post_status'             =>    'publish',
    'post__in'                =>    $sorted_posts,
    'orderby'                 =>    'post__in'
);

$my_query =   new WP_Query($args);
```

But now how I can query the query_post update? I tried to add $my_query = new WP_Query($args)   while ($my_query->have_posts()): $my_query->the_post();

But it doesn't work...

Comment: You can always sort it after retrieving the posts. Basically, you'll grab the posts, then loop through them and sort by whichever calculation you want. Since there isn't a database field, there isn't a way to sort it as it comes in from MySQL, it has to be a separate sort after the posts are retrieved.

Comment: Hello WebElaine and thanks a lot for reply. Can you suggest some guide that explain how to sort posts after retrieving them?

Comment: Why not add it as a meta value to the post after you calculate it, that way when you want to sort price calculated price you now can because it's a meta data of the post

Comment: Hello @Buttered_Toast. Thanks a lof for replies. The value that I'd like use to order my post coming from some calculation of variables and some of them coming from a form that an user shall submit. So I think that It's not possible made your suggestion...

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm experiencing a similar challenge trying to sort `get_posts` results by a calculated value (not stored in field anywhere).